# How to generate current Oracle timestamp in perl?

Tags: oracle, perl

I use DBI. And I want to make some like

```
INSERT INTO ... VALUES (the_generated_timestamp, ...);
```

What is the command? How could it be created, the perl `ocaltime` scalar value has a very complex, for human eyes optimized format (f.e. `Mon Apr 28 15:58:51 2014`). My goal were some like as the unix `gettimeofday()` does (giving back the seconds since 1970.1.1), converted by some format string, which I can let eat by the Oracle.

But any simpler solution were also okay, if it exists.

It need to be generated in perl. `INSERT ... (current_timestamp, ...)` isn't okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this will do:

```
my ($second, $minute, $hour, $day, $month, $year, $weekday, $dayofyear, $dst) = localtime();

my $oracledatestring = sprintf "TO_DATE('%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS')", $year+1900, $month+1, $day, $hour, $minute, $second;
```

.. giving something like:

```
TO_DATE('2014/04/28 16:34:34', 'yyyymmdd HH24:MI:SS')
```

... which can then be inserted directly into an Oracle `DATE` column.

All a bit of a long way round, to be honest. Use `SYSDATE` in your `INSERT` statements instead.